# For loop in Cygwin bash shell followed by ">"

Tags: bash, for-loop, cygwin

When I type the following command in a cygwin bash shell:

```
for i in $(ls) do echo $i done
```

I get a ">" asking me to keep typing, as opposed to the expected behavior. Why?

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs); `for i in *; do ...`.

Comment: Awful way to do this lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate your for, do and done statements.. Try this:

```
for i in $(ls); do echo $i; done
```

You can also separate the statements with newlines.  For exmaple:

```
cygwin$ for i in $(ls)
> do
> echo $i
> done
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop is still waiting for the semicolon or newline that terminates the list of values. So far, your loop with set `i` to the list of words produced by `ls`, the word `do`, the word `echo`, the words produced by the expansion of the *current* value of `i`, and the word `done`.

The `>` is the so-called secondary prompt, which indicates that the shell is still waiting for input to complete the command started by `for`.